# How do I create a new list of dictionaries based on a key-value result?

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries. For example, something like `[{'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'female'}, {'sex':'female'}`. Imagine this, but way bigger.

How would I be able to go though and make a new list with just the male dictionaries? It would look like `[{'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'male'}`

Comment: Are you sure this is the best data structure you could use? Could you provide us with more details? How many values do each dict have in your case?

Answer (score 1):

```py
dict_list_1 = [{'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'female'}, {'sex':'female'}]
dict_list_2 = [dic for dic in dict_list_1 if dic['sex'] == 'male']
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can go about doing this. One of them is using list comprehensions.

```
old_list = [{'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'female'}, {'sex':'female'}]

new_list = [item for item in old_list if item.get('sex') == 'male']
```

However, if your original list had 10 million dictionaries inside, Python would go over the 10 million items before it continues with other stuff.

Another way would be to use a filter, this one is better if you have a very large number of dictionaries in your list because it would not process all of them at once but would rather kind of "stream" them when you use the `new_list` in another loop, the way this would work is as follows. The way filter works is by taking a function that returns either `True` or `False`. This function is then provided every list item. If it returns True, the item stays, if it returns False the item is filtered out.

```
new_list = filter(lambda item: item.get('sex') == 'male', old_list)
```

Be careful that if you have items in your list that are not dictionaries, you would need to make sure that they are dictionaries before calling `.get()` on them. You can do this by changing your conditions to be `isinstance(item, dict) and item.get('sex') == 'male'`

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list_of_data = [{'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'male'}, {'sex':'female'}, {'sex':'female'}]

only_males = [x for x in list_of_data if x['sex'] == 'male']
```